# "Can't find variable" that's let-declared within `with` statement when executing function that's declared within same `with` statement

Tags: javascript, safari, with-statement

Obviously it goes without saying that `with` should be avoided at almost any cost, but this isn't a question about best practices - it's a question about potentially buggy behavior in Safari's JS engine.

My question basically boils down to: Should the following code run without throwing an error?

```js
with({}) {
  let a = 1;
  function foo() {
    console.log(a);
  }
  foo();
}
```

In Firefox and Chrome is does, but Safari throws an error saying that the variable `a` cannot be found. Just confirming that this is a bug, and not the "kinda undefined/unspecified behavior" that we're warned about RE `with` statements.

Changing `let a` to `var a` fixes the error.

https://jsbin.com/hiwihiyaxi/edit?html,console

Comment: Jup, that looks like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I've posted a bug report here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231166